# Every time I enter a room, I get the error "newState.guild.member is not a function"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Consider:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const TOKEN = "I WAS WRITE MT TOKEN"

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { MemberFetchNonceLength } = require("discord.js/src/errors/ErrorCodes");

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} kullanımda`)
})

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err.message)
});

client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async (oldState, newState) => {
  const user = await client.user.fetch(newState.id);
  const member = newState.guild.member(user);

  if (!oldState.channel && newState.channel.id === "I WAS WRITE MY CHANNEL ID") {
    const channel = await newState.guild.channel.create(user.tag, {
      type: "voice",
      parent: newState.channel.parent,
    });
    member.voice.setChannel(channel);
    voiceCollection.set(user.id, channel.id);
  } else if(!newState.channel) {

    if(oldState.channelId === voiceCollection.get(newState.id))
          return oldState.channel.delete();
  }
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

I'm building this bot to set up an automatic voice channel. My code works fine, but it does not create a channel. Every time I enter a voice channel, I get the error "newState.guild.member is not a function".

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Guild` class doesn't contain a method called `member()`.

If you're trying to fetch a specific member, you should use `.fetch()`.

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async (oldState, newState) => {
  // the member's id is the same as it's corresponding user id
  const member = await newState.guild.members.fetch(newState.id);
  ... // etc
```